# Footer gets condenses when window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason the footer items on my page gets condensed and all messed up if you take the browser window and resize it to say 1/2 or 1/4.

[image: Example:]

Link: http://skipq.net/app/index4.php

Footer Code:

```
<footer id='footer'>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="about" style="width:20%;">
      <h1>
        <img width="90" height="90" style="margin-left:130px;" title="This is the icon of app, look for it on your app store!" src="images/iconq.png">
      </h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Available_on_the_App_Store_%28black%29.png" style="margin-left:75px;margin-top:10px;width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a>
      </li><br />
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://www.blog.catblogosphere.com/cb-content/uploads/2013/07/google_play_icon.png" style="margin-left:65px;margin-top:10px;width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="links" style="height:100%;width:20%;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <center>
        <img src="images/thirdicon.png" width="216" height="91">
      <li style="height:100%;width:75%;">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text) > '120'){
            echo substr($text,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="height:100%;width:20%;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <center>
        <img src="images/firsticon.png" width="230" height="90">
      <li style="width:75%;">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text2 = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text2) > '120'){
            echo substr($text2,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text2;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="links" style="height:100%;width:20%;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <center>
        <img src="images/Electronics2.png" width="170" height="91">
      <li style="width:75%;">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li><?php 
          $text2 = "Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing! Just testing!";
          if(strlen($text2) > '120'){
            echo substr($text2,0,100)."...";
            echo '<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a>';
          } else {
            echo $text2;
          }
          ?></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
      </li>
    </ul>
<ul class="links" style="positon:relative;float:left;">
      <li>
        <h4>Connect With Us</h4>
        <ul class="external">
          <li class="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-twitter"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.twitter.com/SkipQ">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-facebook"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.facebook.com/SkipQ">Find us on Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/youtube.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Subscribe on Youtube</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/blog.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Read our Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="container secondary">
<br />
</div>
<div class="secondary" style="padding:2px;color:#FFF;background:#1158D4;">
  <ul>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/help">Help</a></li>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
  <li>&copy; 2013 SkipQ</li>
</ul>
</div>


</footer>
```

If you need more code let me know! I would be happy to give more :)

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4vuh/

Comment: Because it can? `#footer {min-width:2000px}`

Comment: Setting the width to something so large is just a bandage over a gaping wound. A true solution would fix the cause of the problem, not the symptoms.

Comment: I agree, now it only fits certain screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For designing the footer you want you have to wrap all the 5 boxes in its own div and enclose this in a single div and then use the inner div. Also please do note the points from netinept..:)

UPDATE V2.0

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='footer' style="width:1300px;height:50px">
<div class="about" style="width:250px;height:50px;positon:relative;float:left;">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <img title="This is the icon of app, look for it on your app store!" style="margin-left:65px;width:120px;" src="http://skipq.net/app/images/iconq.png">
      </li>
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Available_on_the_App_Store_%28black%29.png" style="margin-left:65px;margin-top:10px;width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a>
      </li><br />
      <li><a target="_top" href="#link"><img src="http://www.blog.catblogosphere.com/cb-content/uploads/2013/07/google_play_icon.png" style="margin-left:65px;margin-top:10px;width:120px;" width="100" height="40"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="links" style="width:250px;height:50px;positon:relative;float:left;">
        <img src="http://skipq.net/app/images/thirdicon.png" width="216" height="91"/>
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
<div class="links" style="width:250px;height:50px;positon:relative;float:left;">
        <img src="http://skipq.net/app/images/firsticon.png" width="230" height="90">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div class="links" style="width:250px;height:50px;positon:relative;float:left;">
      <img src="images/Electronics2.png" width="170" height="91">
        <h4>Title Here</h4>
        <ul style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
          <li>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.<br /><a target="_top" href="random.php" style="color:blue">Read more</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="links" style="width:250px;height:50px;positon:relative;float:left;">
        <h4>Connect With Us</h4>
        <ul class="external">
          <li class="twitter"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-twitter"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.twitter.com/SkipQ">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-facebook"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.facebook.com/SkipQ">Find us on Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/youtube.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Subscribe on Youtube</a></li>
          <li class="blog"><img src="images/blog.png" width="16" height="16"><span class="icon-youtube"></span><a target="_top" href="http://www.youtube.com/">Read our Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: U think you can configure the code and send me a jsfiddle of it? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Replace all the <ul class="links" with div and give width=200px.

Comment: 200px? Why not percentage so it fits all screen sizes?

Comment: And that also didn't fix anything at all.

Comment: Thankyou! This does work sorta but if you rescale your window it just moves the content down, I basically want it so when you rescale your window instead of it just moving the object, the object won't move. The window will just go past the content.

Comment: That works :) But is it possible to do it by percentages so it fits all screens? Because atm it doesn't even fit my screen.

Comment: I dont think so. This would work on most screen. and If you want to do to fit all screens better do it programmatically rather than in css using javascript..Hope that helped..:)

Comment: @user2812028 If you want it to work on different screen sizes, then you want to look into responsive designs and the `@media` query with CSS. There is no reason to use JavaScript for something that's built into CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have `img` elements which are children of `ul`. It is not valid to have anything except an `li` be a child of `ul`.

You are also using the deprecated `center` tag and gratuitous amounts of inline css. First, I recommend re-structuring your footer so that is is valid HTML.

Next, you should use the `overflow:hidden;` CSS rule for elements which have their children spilling out from inside the container, which is the problem you are describing.

Comment: I understand what you mean but how would I do this? Set #footer to overflow:hidden? Because that didn't fix it. I'm sorry if I seem noobish but I am a bit confused.

Comment: @user2812028 Here's a start to what I was talking about. I'm not sure exactly how you want it to look, but this is the general idea http://jsfiddle.net/v4vuh/4/